# Sendkeys event is not detected inside the application in windows form application

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, textbox

I am new to windows app development. I am developing a Windows Form Application where the layout is as follows:

There is one textbox and i have created the keyboard inside the application using SendKeys event.

Problem is that all other application on the system are able to detect the keys but the textbox inside the application is not able to detect the keys.

Basically app is having complete keyboard this is just one button press code

What I have tried:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Control focusedC;
    protected override CreateParams CreateParams
    {
        get
        {
            CreateParams param = base.CreateParams;
            param.ExStyle |= 0x08000000;
            return param;
        }
    }

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
        WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
        TopMost = true;
    }

    private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Escape) {
            FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.Sizable;
            WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
            TopMost = false;
        }
    }

    private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //checkbox is for CapsLock Key
    }

    private void button14_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (checkBox1.Checked && focusedC != null)
        {
            focusedC.Focus();
            SendKeys.Send("Q");
        }
        else if(focusedC != null)
        {
            focusedC.Focus();
            SendKeys.Send("q");
        }
    }
    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        focusedC = sender as TextBox;
    }
}
```

Comment: So, you're saying sendkeys are not sending "Q" as per your code?

Comment: Yes textbox inside the application is not detecting the key, if I open the notepad and start typing then it's working fine, if you want me to add the snapshot of the application then I can do that.

Comment: Ever since Vista, apps shouldn't rely on `SendKeys` working.  You might want to consider _Microsoft UI Automation_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of cource it doesn't work on your window. You set the *WS_EX_NOACTIVATE* style! It works on other windows but not yours, obviously. If you want it to work on your *textbox* remove or comment this line

```
param.ExStyle |= 0x08000000;
```

and it will work fine in your app window **not** others:

```
private void button14_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (checkBox1.Checked)
    {
        textBox1.Focus();
        SendKeys.Send("Q");
    }
    else
    {
        textBox1.Focus();
        SendKeys.Send("q");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For WPF applications, you have to use SendKeys.SendWait() [method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.sendwait.aspx).

`SendKeys.SendWait("Q")`

`SendKeys.Send()` will work for WinForm Applications.

Another option is to use WinAPI instead of SendKeys. More information [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646304(v=vs.85).aspx)

Edit 1

```
Control focusedC;

//Enter event handler for your TextBox

private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    focusedC = sender as TextBox;
}

//Click event handler 
private void  button14_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (focusedC != null)
    {
        focusedC.Focus();
        SendKeys.Send("Q");
    }
}
```

Edit 2: Using WinAPI

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern void SendInput(byte bVk, byte bScan, uint dwFlags, int dwExtraInfo);
  public static void PressKey(byte keyCode)
    {
        const int KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY = 0x1;
        const int KEYEVENTF_KEYUP = 0x2;
        SendInput((byte)keyCode, 0x45, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY, 0);
        SendInput((byte)keyCode, 0x45, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY | KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);

    }
```

Use by calling the PressKey function and Keycodes can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/inputdev/virtual-key-codes)

Comment: I'm using SendKeys.Send() in WinForms Application, key is working fine if I put my cursor in notepad or in any browser but when i put my cursor in textbox inside the same application and then click on the key, then its not working and cursor is removed and highlights the clicked key in app

Comment: so your focus is not set, when you toggle the window ?

Comment: How do i do that then?

Comment: @YogeshYadav - see my updated answer and thanks for replacing WPF tag with Winforms

Comment: i tried the code it's not working, previously key are detected in notepad or browser but now the notepad is also not detecting the key

Comment: Yes, that's because focus is on your Win form only. what exactly do you want. ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174472/discussion-between-yogesh-yadav-and-prany).

Comment: Updated answer using virtual keys